# Cálculo de juros e multas em PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Estou fazendo um código que faz o cálculo de juros e multas no *PHP* com base na quantidade de dias de atraso. Porém estou com problema em conseguir pegar a data e fazer esse cálculo.

```
$databx = new DateTime();
$datavc = new DateTime($bxgst->getDatavencto()); //2018-10-30
$diasatraso = $databx->diff($datavc)->format('%a');

$vm = (($vlprogramado * $vlmulta) / 100);
$vj = (((($pjuros / 30) / 100) * $diasatraso) * 500) + 500;
```

Nesse caso, hoje ele mostra 11 dias, e mostra como se fosse atraso, mas não é, são 11 dias adiantado, não atrasado.

Qual seria a melhor solução?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valide se a data de vencimento é menor que a data atual:

```
$databx = new DateTime();
$datavc = new DateTime($bxgst->getDatavencto()); //2018-10-30

$diasatraso = ($databx->diff($datavc)->format('%r%a') < 0) ? $databx->diff($datavc)->format('%a') : 0;

if($diasatraso > 0){
    $vm = (($vlprogramado * $vlmulta) / 100);
    $vj = (((($pjuros / 30) / 100) * $diasatraso) * 500) + 500;
}else{
    $vm = 0;
    $vj = 0;
}
```

Comment: Você pode substituir o `if` por `format('%r%a')` que ele retornará o sinal correto.

Comment: Testei aqui, mais ele continua mostrando como se fosse dias de atraso.
Exibi 11.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @AndersonCarlosWoss :D

Comment: @JB_ se for adiantado, o valor irá mudar? Se não, você precisa averiguar se o valor recebido é negativo, caso contrário o preço ficará menor pagando adiantado.

Comment: Nessa condição se pagar adiantado, o valor não sofre alteração, porém se pagar atrasado há cobrança de juros e multas com base na quantidade de dias de atraso.

Comment: @JB_ acho que entendi o que vc precisa, vou alterar o código

Comment: Se o cliente pagar até o vencimento, preciso que seja 0 os dias de atraso, somente se houver atrasos que entra juros e multas com base na quantidade de dias de atraso.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 2):

Se a multa será aplicada apenas em caso de atraso, acredito que validar apenas se a data de pagamento é maior que a do vencimento deva resolver:

```
$databx = new DateTime();
$datavc = new DateTime($bxgst->getDatavencto()); //2018-10-30

//caso precise das variáveis zeradas, se estiver no prazo
$diasatraso = 0;
$vm = 0;
$vj = 0;

if (date_format($databx, "Y-m-d") > date_format($datavc, "Y-m-d")) {
   $diasatraso = $databx->diff($datavc)->format('%a');

   $vm = (($vlprogramado * $vlmulta) / 100);
   $vj = (((($pjuros / 30) / 100) * $diasatraso) * 500) + 500;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.